# Present a view controller on top of UIImagePickerController instead of dismissing the UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

I am developing an app where I have to use the image picker controller to import an image from the library of the phone. The problem is I have first to dismiss the picker controller then present another controller after the picker controller dismisses. Is there a way where I do not have to dismiss the image picker controller, but instead present a view controller or a nav controller. By the way, if I do not dismiss the imagePickerController, it will crash. Second, I am presenting a view controller that passes the image that was selected.
Thank you.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let shViewController = SHViewController()

        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            shViewController.image = editedImage
        } else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            shViewController.image = originalImage
        }


        shViewController.delegate = self

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        present(shViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: try `picker.present(shViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` and comment `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Call `present` in the completion handler of `dismiss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't present 2 vc from the same vc , so either

```
picker.present(shViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**OR**

```
dismiss(animated:false) {
   self.present(shViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The second block of code dismiss then present have the same problem where it dismisses then wait for 2 seconds then present the controller which does not solve the problem. But, the first code where you present the picker it worked for me when you present the shViewController. The problem occurs where I dismiss the shViewController, and the picker is still not is not dismissed.

Comment: try `dismiss(animated: false)`